# json_encode and fwrite of php not able to recognize binary data why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fwrite

json_encode of php and fwrite of php not able to recognize binary data why ?

When i am taking some image in binary format then trying to convert in json format when calling in ajax from javascript/jquery side, it is showing null. Again when trying to write the data in a file via fwrite() of php then also it has written null only.

I solved this issue using base64 encode format. The base64 format can be writable to file as well as taken to json encode format too.

May be json_encode() and fwrite() of php is for texts only.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to send binary data using json. One thing to keep in mind is that the data is always transferred as string. In order to send binary data, convert the binary number into string and then json_encode it as

```
{
  "array": [
    010101000,
    100010001,
    010001001
  ]
}
```

The binary number shown above is actually string. On client side, you have to interpret this string as binary.

If you want to use ajax call to fetch data from server, you should use base64 encoding rather than binary.